# sharedPreferences.getStringSet() devuelve default value (null) (Android)

Tags: android-studio

En la clase UtilUser me he creado un método para devolver una lista de id's de anuncios favoritos.

```
public static Set<String> getFavs(Context mContext) {
    setSharedPreferences(mContext);
    Set<String> favs = new HashSet<>();
    favs = sharedPreferences
            .getStringSet("favs", null);

    return favs;
}
```

Y al llamarlo en el adapter de listar anuncios, quiero mostrar el botón de añadir/quitar de favoritos, en función de si el id del anuncio se encuentra en la lista que nos devuelve getFavs(Context mcontext), mediante el siguiente if

```
if(UtilUser.getFavs(this.contexto).contains(this.mValues.get(position).getId())){
            Log.d("d", "es favorito");
        }
```

El problema está en que getFavs siempre devuelve el default value (null)

Comment: Creo que debes mostrar cuando estableces la preferencia. Creo que es el método  `setSharedPreferences()`

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Has comprobado que el contexto que estás pasando tenga valor diferente de `null`? Un saludo.

Comment: El contexto que le paso es distinto de `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te regresa nulo por que al momento de crear el `sharedPreferences` debes establecer un valor por `default`, que el mismo sera devuelto en caso de que la preferencia se encuentre vacía, debes tener en cuenta también que debes setear el valor en algún lugar antes de usar el método `getPreferences`, lo comento por que no veo en ningún momento que estés seteando un valor en la key "favs". Entonces, lo que debes hacer primero es:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref  = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref .edit();
    editor.putString(key, save);
    editor.apply();
```

En donde dice `context` aplicarías el contexto de la actividad, el fragment, etc. En la linea `editor.putString(key, save)`, introduces la `key`, en tu caso "favs" y `save`, seria el `String` que deseas guardar, ya estando guardado bajo esa `key` al momento en que uses el método get del preference, podrás obtener el valor donde desees.